# How to make more use of the separator line? E.g. making it a cell?

Tags: ios, click, tableview

I was wondering, how you could do something like this, e.g. make the separator line usable, in this example as a display of votes. I think the separator line is a cell here. When you click on it a popover menu comes and you can click what you want to vote for. My question is: Does someone know how to do that or has a link to a useful explanation?

[image: separator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the "seperators" are actual cells, but rather part of the previous cell. You can see that the indicatorview is seemingly not centered vertically (which I personally even find sloppy).

So, just make a custom cell with your desired behavior. Maybe google for "Accordeon cell" or something like that, I think I remember they talked about cells like that in the previous WWDCs.

Comment: Thanks, but they just expand the cell. I don't want to do that. I want every cell to have a underline like in the picture and when I click on it, a popover menu comes. But my initial question is: How to implement such a underlining?

Comment: It's not an "underlining". It's just that the "previous" cell has -say - a button on the bottom. The "previous" cell AND the "underlining" are in fact one single custom cell.

Comment: Sorry for my english, I think I misspoke there: Yes you are right and I understand. But I was wondering how they do that. Maybe with custom placed labels? As far as I understand a accordion cell just expands, it doesn't add the "button on the bottom". I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: Google for "custom cell". In your case, a simple, properly styled, UIButton (button width = cell width) on the bottom of the custom cell will suffice